# php SEO urls rewriting by keywords and queries from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, url, seo

First, in .htaccess file i put this lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)?$ index.php?key=$1 [L]
```

I got also table in MySQL

```
| aliasID |     query     | keyword |
--------------------------------------
|    1    | site=articles | articles |
```

Now in index.php i got

```
    if(isset($_GET['key'])) $key = $_GET['key'];
    else $key = '';

    if($key) 
    { 

        $invalide = array('\\','/','/\/',':','.');
        $key = str_replace($invalide,' ',$key);

        $checkiskey=mysql_fetch_array(safe_query("SELECT * FROM seoaliasy WHERE keyword='".$key."'"));

        if($checkiskey) {

            // here missing code

        } else { echo '404'; }

    } else {

    echo 'main page';

    }
```

Now i want to know what code i need to put in "//here missing code" place that include content of page called from MySQL query of MySQL column.

The properly address of site is www.example.com/index.php?site=articles (if this was entered in address bar of internet browser the page was appears corectly)... but i need that the same page must be included after if in address bar i put http://www.example.com/articles (so query [site=articles] from correctly address was converted to key from [keyword] column in MySQL)

Simple, i looking solution for simple SEO URL rewriting based on MySQL table with "queries" and "keywords".

Comment: this will have **0** effect on your search engine ranking. But if you have nothing better to do - carry on

Comment: search engine ranking for me is future problem .. now i need to find solution to got effect which is described above.. is any way to got this by no advenced code?

Comment: reading it again ,your just asking how to echo content from a db?

Comment: No! I have simple PHP CMS which works fine, but without SEO firendly URLs. Now i need simple solution to "echo" content from url queries (index.php?[site=articles][site=contact][site=articles&articlesID=423] etc.) sutiable for this what is in MySQL column named "query", but by the key from "keyword" column.

Comment: still confused `here missing code` you just need to echo the data returned by `$checkiskey` ?

Comment: No. This MySQL query is only for checking the alias which is induced in address is in database. If you go to example.com/articles,"articles" key must be in MySQL table.. if is not then 404 page appears.. if the $checkiskey find row with "articles" keyword then choose content of "query" column (in this case site=articles) and echo content from address "index.php?site=articles" (which works fine when u use this address in the browser manualy - i need that this same content was appear when i use not index?site=articles but only "articles" placed after main address eg. www.site.com/articles).

Comment: but where is the contents of `"index.php?site=articles` stored ?

Comment: Ahhh. OK.. You ask for this. Yeap. The articles page have own MySQL table with list of articles ... |artID|title|content|date|category etc... As i wrote before. This is simple PHP CMS with own code... but all pages are loaded by page address with queries... index.php?site=article have own file with content which load the articles from database...

Comment: OpenCart also have in own database table oc_url_alias with columns id|query|keyword.. and if you go to address shop.com/Nokia-2330 the shop.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1188 page was appear (query column have "product_id=1188", keyword column have "Nokia-2330")

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from where you want to access the data. However You can call content of any page  in PHP by using CURL

```
    $ch = curl_init("YOUR_PAGE_URL");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);       
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output;
```

Comment: he wants the data from a db; and you should never use curl on a local file

Comment: Do you want data from DB @X9DESIGN ? Yes Dagon curl should not be used in local file but I am not clear from his question from where he wants the content.

Comment: No. he don't understand completly what i need..you follow the right track for this what i need, but after all your solution is also not work for me.. 400 Bad Request

Comment: Can you send me the code here how you are using this solution. 400 error shows something wrong in HTTP request.